# hibernate non-unique one to one mapping

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

we are working with a legacy database and I'm wondering if our set up is at all possible with Hibernate the way it is:

We have two tables Entity and EntityDef

```sql
CREATE TABLE entity
( 
  id DOUBLE,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE entitydef 
( 
  id DOUBLE,
  effectivedate DATE,
  terminationdate DATE,
  category VARCHAR(20),

  PRIMARY KEY (id, terminationdate)
)
```

Basically for every Entity it can have multiple corresponding EntityDef's that specify parameters for a particular effective period. These EntityDef's effective periods are disjoint so at any given time there should be a one-to-one relationship between an Entity and an EntityDef. The problem comes when trying to use hibernate to map the Entity table. We use the following mappings

```xml
<class name="com.company.Entity" table="Entity">
    <cache usage="read-write" />
    <id name="id" type="long">
        <column name="id" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" />
    </property>
    <join table="entitydef">
        <key>
            <column name="id" sql-type="long />
        </key>
        <property name="category" type="string">
            <column name="category" />
        </property>
    </join>
</class>

<class name="com.company.EntityDef" table="entitydef">
    <cache usage="read-write" />
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="id" type="long">
            <column name="id" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="terminationDate" type="com.company.time.hibernate.Date">
            <column name="terminationdate" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="category">
        <column name="category" />
    </property>
</class>
```

The problem arises when a different hibernate mapping references an Entity with multiple EntityDefs by only its ID.

```xml
...
<many-to-one name="entity" class="com.company.Entity" lazy="false">
    <column name="entityid" />
</many-to-one>
...
```

Hibernate queries for the Entity by its ID and throws an exception which makes sense:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 1, for class: com.company.Entity
```

We tried adding a filter to the EntityDef mapping as shown in the Hibernate documentation:

```xml
<filter-def name="effectiveDate">
    <filter-param name="asOfDate" type="date" />
</filter-def>   
<class name="com.company.EntityDef" table="entitydef">
    <cache usage="read-write" />
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="id" type="long">
            <column name="id" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="terminationDate" type="com.company.time.hibernate.Date">
            <column name="terminationdate" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="category">
        <column name="category" />
    </property>
    <filter name="effectiveDate" condition=":asOfDate BETWEEN effectivedate and terminationdate" />
</class>
```

And added the following code to our queries:

```java
sess.enableFilter("effectiveDate").setParameter("asOfDate", new Date());
```

But that didn't seem to affect anything.

My question is this: is this setup even possible and is there a way to join with the EntityDef table without specifying the termination date explicitly? If not what would be the best solution? Creating a one-to-many relationship and using logic in the Entity class to fetch the correct EntityDef from the collection?

There is a lot of business logic that expects the category and the like to be part of the Entity so if we didn't have to resort to a one-to-many relationship that would be excellent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, that a combination of your suggestion and filter technique

- Creating a one-to-many relationship and using logic in the Entity class to fetch the correct EntityDef from the collection
- using `<filter>`

could do the job.

Instead of mapping *joined* class Entity, let's have an `Entity` with a collection of `EntityDef`. So, instead of mapping

```
<join table="entitydef">
```

use collection mapping with filter:

```
<set name="entityDefs" inverse="true">
  <key column="id"/>
  <one-to-many class="com.company.EntityDef"/>
  <filter name="effectiveDate" condition=":asOfDate BETWEEN effectivedate and terminationdate" />
</set>
```

In case *(as stated in the question)*, there is always `one-to-one` mapping to given time, we need to inject the filter into session `sess.enableFilter("effectiveDate")...` (e.g. some AOP to be sure)

Now, we always have collection of `EntityDefs` containing exactly **one** item. So we can hide manipulation with this first record in `entity.category` accessors.

We are using it like this. It requires more logic on `Entity` creation, but at the end it also supports projection over EntityDef (not effecting paging, thanks to *filter* always 1 row is returned)

Comment: Hi Radim, thanks for the suggestion. I think this is definitely the best solution as we can implement it without the business layer knowing about the change at all. From further research it looks like Hibernate filters cannot change the cardinality of a relationship (e.g. from one-to-many to one-to-one) though it would be nice if Hibernate supported some notion of effective dating.

Comment: We are using this approach also for different slices e.g. country, not only Date. And exactly as you said: we've changed the DL implementation (in our case later) to apply this requirement, and none of the other parts was effected... good luck with Hibernate ;)